# How to avoid the duplicate values in List box

Tags: vb6

Table1

```
ID Division Dept

001 CS IT
002 CD Admin
003 AS Admin
```

I want to load the dept in the list box with out duplicate values

Tried Code

```
Dim rdoRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim record As Variant
Dim Div As Variant
Dim usr, MySQL As String
usr = "CD,AS,"
record = Split(usr, ",")
For Each Div In record
MySQL = "Select Distinct dept from table1 Where division = '" & div & "'"
   rdoRs.Open MySQL, conn1
   If rdoRs.RecordCount > 0 Then
      Do While Not rdoRs.EOF
         listbox1.AddItem rdoRs!dept
           rdoRs.MoveNext
           Loop
   End If
   rdoRs.Close
Next
```

Output

```
Listbox1

Admin 'Loaded for CD Division
Admin 'Loaded for AS Division
```

The above code is working fine but it is loading 2 times admin dept. in the list box.  Because For Loop is loading the dept admin for CD, and again it is loading the dept admin for AS division.

I dont want to show duplicate values in the list box.

Expected Output

```
Listbox1

Admin  'Loaded for both CD and AS Division
```

How to do this in VB6.

Need VB6 Code Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function to check if it's already in the list...

```
Public Function FindInList(theList as ListBox, theString as String)
    Dim i as Integer
    theString = LCase(Trim(theString))

    For i = 0 to theList.ListCount - 1
        If LCase(Trim(theList.List(i))) = theString then
            FindInList = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    FindInList = -1
End Function
```

And then when you want to add things to the list, just do...

```
If FindInList(List1, StringToAdd) = -1 Then List1.AddItem(StringToAdd)
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the code where it compared an LCase()'d string against a string of unknown case.  This would have caused the code to not work.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the query

Change

```
MySQL = "Select dept from table1 Where division = '" & div & "'"
```

to something like

```
MySQL = "Select DISTINCT dept from table1 Where division = '" & div & "'"
```

Comment: please under stand my question, i dont have problem in SQL Query and also i know the distinct values, For Loop is giving duplicate values...

Comment: It should not give duplicated values if you are using DISTINCT